# What is mercury-like liquid on 2nd stage SpaceX engine

Tags: rocket-science

I was watching this:
https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=UM8CDDAmp98

At around 22:33 It showed one side of the engine with what looked like some sort of liquid running on it.

The liquid was at the top of the cone and was running circularly along it. The rocket is in space, so that’s not water. It is ludicrously unlikely to be mercury. It looked like some sort of liquid came out of the bag, and dripped on the rocket nozzle. It is only showing on one side of the engine, and not the other. It looks like it travels around a weld.

At first I thought it might be some sort of reflected sunlight, or light reflected from the earth or something. After I watched it though, it moved, and it moved like droplets along a surface in bumps and starts.

Is this some sort of liquefied gas? Is this some sort of melting polymer? I would imagine the rocket engine is very hot so maybe it’s a liquid metal, some sort of alloy that has melted.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this is more suited to Space Exploration SE.

Comment: @StephenG - I didn't know "Space Exploration" existed, thanks for pointing it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My hypothesis is that it is little shreds of a foil or plastic sheet, presumably the foil that is wrapped around the engine.

The telemetry data shown in the corner say that the rocket is at 167 km altitude, speed is about 20.000 km/h.

If it is shreds of foil/sheet: the rocket is accelerating hard (velocity telemetry increasing rapidly), so if the material is stuck on some ledge it would require a considerable push to push it off that ledge. I have no way of guessing whether the motion of the material is due to engine nozzle vibration, or some turbulence effect. (I don't know how thin the atmosphere is at that altitude, and I don't know what such a thin atmosphere can do at Mach 20.)

Shreds of foil/sheet is my hypothesis because it seems to me that foil/sheet is the only material present that could possibly account for it.

---

Below is a link to 22:30 into the video (link obtained using the 'copy video URL at current time' feature of youtube)

When played at 0.25 speed I see a shred of foil come loose and join the other shreds.

https://youtu.be/UM8CDDAmp98?t=1350

Comment: likely melted foil, the bell is glowing red just below it.